# The set of all point x such that $|x−a|<\delta$ is called a $\delta$ neighborhood of the point a. Why is there no equality.?

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone tell methat why is there no equality in the definition of delta nhd of a point?

The set of all point $x$ such that $|x−a|<\delta$ is called a $\delta$ neighborhood of the point $a$.
Why is there no equalit.?

Comment: This is because it has to be an *open* neighbourhood to satisfy the axioms of open sets.

Comment: If you consider an open set as a set of points "near" the point in question, it becames more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Because neighborhood is an open set by definition. And assuming we impose the regular metric and the standard topology your open sets are open intervals of real line.

Comment: I'm sorry, there are also closed neighbourhoods.

Comment: Usually, we define a neighborhood of a point to be an open set containing that point. (Did you mean in topology constricted by closed sets rather than open ones? Is so I don’t think it’s the most conventional, even though completely equivalent)

Comment: The word "neighborhood" is indeed defined in different ways, depending on what you are reading. In some sources a "neighborhood" of $x$ is defined to be an open subset that contains $x$, and in other sources it is defined to be a subset $A$ such that the interior of $A$ contains $x$. Elementary topology books seem to prefer the former (as do I), but plenty of books that apply topology use the latter.

Comment: A neighborhood is sometimes defined to be a set containing an open set containing the point; for example, I think Rudin’s functional analysis book uses this definition.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand..i am studying functions of several variables in which the same definition of delta nhd Has extended to more than one one variables. The only confusion is that what happened if we apply equality in definition or if not then what absurdity occurs in definition? If equality hold then whether it would be boundary point?

Comment: The general definition of a neighbourhood of a point  is any superset of an open set containing  that point. Whence this characterisation of an open set: it is a neighbourhood of each of its points.

Comment: @NaseemAkhtar do you mean why is it not the case that $x-a \leq \delta$? Or  $x-a= \delta$?

Comment: @khachatryan yes exactly..sir you understand my question

Comment: @NaseemAkhtar my question was not a yes or no question; you need to say the first option or the second.

Comment: @NaseemAkhtar if the boundary point is included, then you have a closed set (in usual definition with usual topoly) and therefore you don’t have a neighborhood which is by definition an open set

Comment: @Elen Khachatryan yes 1st option..

Comment: @NaseemAkhtar did you read my explanation above your comment? Is it not clear? And if so, which part of it?